# F# Compilation error with nested generics

Tags: generics, f#, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a simple wrapper that I use to add aditional data to an arbitrary object:

```
type Wrapper<'T>(data:'T) =
  member val Data:'T=data with get
  member val AdditionalProperty:int=0 with get
```

Then I use those elements in a singly linked list, where I want to constraint the items to be of `Wrapper<'T>`, the elements are defined:

```
type LListItem<'T>(data:Wrapper<'T>) =
  member val Data:Wrapper<'T>=data with get
  member val Prev:LListItem<'T> option = None with get, set
```

And then I pretend to manage the linked list with this class:

```
 1| type LList<'T>()=
 2|   let mutable last:LListItem<Wrapper1<'T>> option = None
 3|   member x.Append(wrapped:Wrapper1<'T>)=
 4|     let item = new LListItem<'T>(wrapped)
 5|     match last with
 6|     | None -> 
 7|       last <- Some item
 8|     | Some l -> 
 9|       item.Prev <- last
10|      last <- Some item
```

But in this `Append` method, I these compilation errors:

- Line 1 :This type parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be 'Wrapper<'T>'
- Line 1 :This code is less generic than required by its annotations because the explicit type variable 'T' could not be generalized. It was constrained to be 'Wrapper<'T>'.
- Line 3 :The generic member 'Append' has been used at a non-uniform instantiation prior to this program point. Consider reordering the members so this member occurs first. Alternatively, specify the full type of the member explicitly, including argument types, return type and any additional generic parameters and constraints.

I am doing something fundamentally wrong here, but I don't understand the compiler messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error message, because the type inference somehow infers that the generic type parameter `'T` is always constrained to be `Wrapper<'T>`. This usually happens when you have some code that takes a value of type `'T` and passes it somewhere where `Wrapper<'T>` is expected.

In your case, this happens when you're setting `last` in the `LList` type. The type annotation defines that the type is `LListItem<Wrapper<'T>> option`:

```
type LList<'T>()=
  let mutable last:LListItem<Wrapper<'T>> option = None
```

But when you are assigning the value, the argument is `LListItem<'T>`. So you need to change the above line to this:

```
type LList<'T>()=
  let mutable last:LListItem<'T> option = None
```

I suspect that `LListItem<Wrapper<'T>>` is an error because `LListItem` *always* takes wrapped arguments.

**EDIT**: The other option to fix this is to change `LListItem` so that it *never* takes wrapped arguments - which is what Gustavo's answer suggests.